# How to convert the list to be the list of <a href> to next and prev

Tags: html, html-lists

I have the code like this:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#a">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#b">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#c">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#d">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#e">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#f">6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#g">7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#h">8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#j">9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#k">10</a></li>
        </ul>
```

How to convert the list to be the only 2 dynamic button
Next and Previous like

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#a">Previous</a></li>
            <li><a href="#b">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
```

if (href == #a) then the previous button is disabled.
so on with the href == #k

### **UPDATE**

HTML:

```
<a id="prevNav" href="#start" onclick="moveNav(-1);">Previous</a>
<a id="nextNav" href="#description" onclick="moveNav(1);">Next</a>
```

JS:

```
var nextPrevNav = new Array("#start",
                        "#follow",
                        "#test1",
                        "#test2");

var curpos = 0;
function moveNav(dir) {
    (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;  
    curpos = curpos + dir;
    if(curpos<0) {
        curpos = 0;
    }
    //window.location.hash = nextPrevNav[curpos];
    if (dir<0){
        document.getElementById('prevNav').href = nextPrevNav[curpos];
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('nextNav').href = nextPrevNav[curpos];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's easier to track the prev/next position in JavaScript and have a single set of buttons rather than manipulating the UI after every click. If that is an acceptable solution, I can post an example.

Comment: Yes javascript needed, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows you to set up a simple next/previous anchor jump:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="move(-1)">prev</a> <a href="#" onclick="move(1)">next</a>
```

JS:

```
var positions = "abcdefghijk";
var curpos = 0
function move(dir) {
    (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;  
    curpos = curpos + dir;
    if(curpos<0) {
        curpos = 0;
    }
    if(curpos>positions.length-1) {
        curpos = positions.length-1;
    }
    window.location.hash == '#'+positions[curpos]; 
}
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Diodeus, i wanted to change element href="#..." onclick, cause with window,location.hash it didn't working. how to do that? :)

Comment: Do you have named anchors for each hash value in your document?

Comment: You can use: var nextPrevNav = "start,follow,test1,test2".split"(",") to use your own anchor name values.